# Ensuring the next function only runs after dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dialog component, and when the dialog closes, the user's input is registered. This input is then used in a check on whether to run the next function or not.

However, I realised that the variable is never immediately changed to what the user has chosen, it remains undefined until the next time the dialog is open and closed again.

I read that Javascript runs functions synchronously by default, so I tried to separate them into two different functions but to no avail as well.

Here's the code:

```
   openDialog() {
      const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
        context: {
          name: this.name,
          details: this.details,
        },
      }).onClose.subscribe(confirm => this.confirm = confirm);

      console.log(this.confirm); //returns undefined

      if (this.confirm === true) { //doesn't run until dialog is opened and closed the second time
        console.log('true');
        this.record();
      }
    }
```

*p.s. I'm using the angular ngx-admin library for my dialog. So .onClose() === .afterClosed() for the normal angular dialog.*

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: hi @PrashantPimpale, I'm using an ngx-library for the dialog, so .onClose() is actually .afterClosed() in this case (i.e. already in my code!)

Comment: Can you provide Stackblitz where I can run above code?

Comment: Every thing inside the subscribe will be run after being closed but everything after will run after a subscription is made and will run too early. Use `.subscribe(confirm => { // multiple lines of code incl setting this.confirm});`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I was trying to create a Stackblitz but I couldn't figure out how to import all the necessary things for @angular/material. But the question has been answered, so thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your code Inside **subscribe()** method, something like:

```
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
        context: {
            name: this.name,
            details: this.details,
        },
    }).onClose.subscribe(confirm => { 
        if(confirm) {
            console.log(confirm);
            this.record();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this was so obvious I'm ashamed of myself. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, the most important thing is that you are trying ;) Remember, always: `.subscribe( parameter => { /* Do your magic with parameter */ });`